# PowerShell is re-arranging my columns and i cant figure out why

Tags: powershell, csv

The code I am using is below:

```
Import-Csv -Path "E:\CSV\GA.csv"  | Group-Object Product | ForEach {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Product = $_.Name 
        Stockcode = $_.Group[0].Stockcode
        QuantityCounted = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property QuantityCounted -Sum).Sum    
    }
} | Export-Csv "E:\CSV\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The Headers should be in this order:

```
Product | Stockcode | QuantityCounted
```

[image]

If someone could point me in the right direction that would awesome, thank you.

Comment: Use the *type accelerator*: `[Pscustomobject]@{..} | Export-..`, otherwise specify it to be *ordered*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hash Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) are not ordered by default, if you need your object's properties to preserve their order you need to use an [Ordered Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries) instead.

> The `[ordered]` attribute is introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

```bash
New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
    Product         = 1
    Stockcode       = 2
    QuantityCounted = 3
})
```

If you're running an *up-to-date* version of PowerShell, you can create objects with ordered properties using the [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) type accelerator. This is more efficient and straight forward than [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7.2).

> The `[pscustomobject]` type accelerator was added in PowerShell 4.0.

```bash
[pscustomobject]@{
    Product         = 1
    Stockcode       = 2
    QuantityCounted = 3
}
```